# Position absolute shifting to the right in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a banner rotator JQuery script running at the top of my page, fading images in and out. It works perfectly in all browsers apart from IE. The border sits in the correct position, however the images shift to the right. I have played around and found it is due to my absolute positioning.

```
#bannerRotator { width:969px; height:226px; margin:20px auto; background:white; border-    style: solid; border-width:5px; border-color:white; border-radius: 10px;}
#bannerRotator ul li img{ max-width:969px; max-height:226px; }

#bannerRotator { position:relative; }
#bannerRotator ul { list-style:none; padding:0; position:relative; margin:0; }
#bannerRotator ul li { display:none; position:absolute; left:0px;}
#bannerRotator ul li a { text-decoration:none; }
#bannerNav { position:absolute; right:15px; bottom:15px; background:url(./img/transBlack75.png) repeat 0 0; padding:5px 5px 5px 10px; }
#bannerNav a { margin:3px 10px 0 0; height:10px; width:10px; display:block; background:url(./img/dotDark.png) no-repeat 0 0; float:left; }
#bannerNav a.active { background-image:url(./img/dotLight.png); }
#bannerNav span.pause, #bannerNav span.play { cursor:pointer; height:15px; width:15px; display:block; background:url(img/pause.png) no-repeat 0 0; float:left; }
#bannerNav span.play { background-image:url(./img/play.png) }
```

The HTML is as follows

```
<div id="bannerRotator">
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src="./images/bannerImage1.jpg" alt="bannerImage1">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="./images/Newbury.jpg" alt="bannerImage2">
    </a
  ></li>
  <li>
      <img src="./images/bannerImage3.jpg" alt="bannerImage3">
    </a
  ></li>
  <li>
      <img src="./images/bannerImage4.jpg" alt="bannerImage4">
    </a
  ></li>
  <li>
      <img src="./images/bannerImage5.jpg" alt="bannerImage5">
    </a
  ></li>         
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: your should add css tag for this.

Comment: have you got the html for the banner rotator - would be quite useful

Comment: Added the html to the above code